# Recursive system

Tags: system-identification

Trying to identify if the system below is recursive or not, I would think a recursive system present output value would depend of a past output and not on a present output value.

Is

$$Y[n] = X[n] - Y[n] $$

a recursive system?

Comment: Do you need past outputs to compute the current output?

Comment: No just the current outputs as feedback to compute current output.

Comment: Well, then there is no feedback; you can't use the current output to compute the current output, right?

Answer (score 4):

No, it can be rewritten as $y[n] = x[n]/2$. Basically, the output is the input divided by 2...